# C++11 memory orderings- the differences?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, atomic

I am currently reading Concurrency in Action and on page 111 it gives this sample code relating to a `std::atomic_flag` in order to explain how memory orderings work:

```
f.clear(std::memory_order_release);
bool x = f.test_and_set();
```

but all it says is:

> Here, the call to `clear()`explicitly requests that the flag is
>   cleared with release semantics, while the call to `test_and_set()`
>   uses the default memory ordering for setting the flag and retrieving
>   the old value.

They haven't actually explained what the differences are. Could somebody provide a general overview of how these memory orderings work? So not just the one I have mentioned above, but I believe there are a few more:

```
memory_order_relaxed
memory_order_release
memory_order_seq_cst
memory_order_consume
memory_order_acquire
memory_order_acq_rel
```

Comment: They have a decent overview here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Comment: Could you please explain what this means though: "A load operation with this memory order performs a consume operation on the affected memory location: prior writes to data-dependent memory locations made by the thread that did a release operation become visible to this thread."

Comment: @user997112: Read further down into that memory_order documentation. They explain the difference between acquire and consume. Acquire makes all previous memory operations before a release visible. Consume only makes visible memory that had an affect on the atomic variable. It also says that the only CPU they know of that makes a difference is Alpha. But that doesn't guarantee someone won't reuse that memory design in the future.

Comment: If you continue reading the book it will explain all the differences in more detail than you ever wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Informal characterisation (take it with a sack of salt):

- **SEQ_CST:** the code behaves as if it was a simple interleaving of threads, with no reordering observable, as long as there are no data races.
- **RELEASE/ACQUIRE:** A release "publishes" a write, and a read on that same memory location synchronizes with that write. As an example, a mutex lock may do an **ACQUIRE**, and a mutex unlock a **RELEASE**. Another example:

Example (atomic operations marked with their memory order on parenthesis):

```
t1:                                   t2:
   data = foo                            while not data_valid; (ACQUIRE)
   data_valid = true; (RELEASE)          bar = data;
```

- **ACQ_REL:** does both an acquire and a release, for atomic RMW (Read-Modify-Write) operations. Note that you can specify to use **ACQ_REL** for a sucessful RMW, and another memory order if the RMW operation fails.
- **RELEASE/CONSUME:** You publish a pointer to a structure, and a read "consumes" that publication, and can access the pointed-to data. Some Alpha processors had split caches, which meant that you could be reading a pointer from a bank of a cache, and the pointed-to data may not be still on other bank from that cache. In RCU as implemented on Linux, `rcu_derefence()` takes care of inserting a read barrier on Alpha between the read of the pointer and its dereference. Note that there has been some talk on totally changing the specification of the consume memory order (on a mailing list thread called ["arch: atomic rework"](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/2/6/193)), as it seems to be impractical for compiler writers. In particular, the current standard allows you to publish `p`, and `*(q + (p-p))` is dependant on that. Some people contend that makes no sense at all.
- **RELAXED:** Free for all.

Comment: Even is there are race conditions, seq_cst would simply guarantee that some arbitrary order will be observed by all threads.

Comment: @Leeor: Ok, I used the wrong term. Should have been _data races_, which invoke Undefined Behavior.